# How to use babel-loader with native es6 modules?

Tags: javascript, webpack, babeljs, es6-modules, babel-loader

I'm use native es6 modules on static site.

```
<script type="module" src="./main.js"></script>
```

Before deploying, I  pass js files through babel

// webpack.config.js

```
rules: [
  {
    test: /\.js$/i,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: ['babel-loader'],
  }
]
```

// .babelrc

```
  {
      "presets": [
        [
          "@babel/preset-env",
          {
            "modules": false,
          }
        ]
      ]
    }
```

By default babel turns modules into common js, although I have a flag "modules": false in my .babelrc

I don't want babel to turn modules into commonjs, I just want to turn everything except import and export in es2015, so that I can use native modules in the browser

Like this:
// main.js before

```
export default () => {
  return 'Hello world!'
}
```

// main.js after babel

```
export default function () {
  return 'Hello world!'
}
```

According to the documentation babel provides a module: false option, but it doesn't work for me

Also, not working caller with supportsStaticESM

```
  {
    test: /\.js$/i,
    exclude: /node_modules/,
    use: {
      loader: 'babel-loader',
      options: {
        presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],
        caller: {
          supportsStaticESM: true
        }
      }
    }
  }
```

However, when I use babel-cli I get what I need!

i think webpack is not friendly with babel in this case

Thanks.

```
"babel-loader": "8.0.5"
"webpack": "^5.40.0"
```

Answer (score 0):

For me just specifying `target` did the trick.

```
module.exports = {
    entry: './js/index.js',
    // ...
    target: ['web', 'es5']
}
```

Comment: did not help (.  the output turned out:  !function(){"use strict"}();

Comment: Can u show me u webpack.config.js and .babelrc?

Answer (score 0):

If it works with Babel but not with Webpack, then most likely Webpack configuration overrides setting from Babel.

Please try to remove `presets: ['@babel/preset-env'],` from Webpack config (if  present).